# Djongo Error = AttributeError: 'Identifier' object has no attribute 'get_parameters'

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, djongo, django-oauth-toolkit

My system environment.

```
Django==4.1.4
django-oauth-toolkit==2.2.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djongo==1.3.6
pymongo==3.12.3
```

Execute this.

```
python manage.py cleartokens
```

I got this error => AttributeError: 'Identifier' object has no attribute 'get_parameters'.
But I can't find a 'get_parameters' function.
The djongo package does not define a get_parameters function.
Is this a version problem?
My djongo is a latest version. It's a 1.3.6 version.
Where is a get_parameters function?
How can fix a sql error?

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 857, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 933, in _select
    return SelectQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 116, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 123, in parse
    self.selected_columns = ColumnSelectConverter(self, statement)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py", line 44, in __init__
    super().__init__(query, statement)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py", line 53, in parse
    for sql_token in SQLToken.tokens2sql(tok, self.query):
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/sql_tokens.py", line 49, in tokens2sql
    yield SQLFunc.token2sql(token, query)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/functions.py", line 24, in token2sql
    return CountFunc.token2sql(token, query)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/functions.py", line 78, in token2sql
    token[0].get_parameters()[0]
AttributeError: 'Identifier' object has no attribute 'get_parameters'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 885, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

    Keyword: None
    Sub SQL: None
    FAILED SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT "oauth2_provider_refreshtoken"."id" AS "col1" FROM "oauth2_provider_refreshtoken" WHERE "oauth2_provider_refreshtoken"."revoked" < %(0)s LIMIT 1000) subquery
    Params: (datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 17, 23, 33, 36, 264763),)
    Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/python_backend/MgBackApi/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/python_backend/MgBackApi/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2_provider/management/commands/cleartokens.py", line 10, in handle
    clear_expired()
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2_provider/models.py", line 682, in clear_expired
    revoked_deleted_no = batch_delete(revoked, revoked_query)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2_provider/models.py", line 651, in batch_delete
    batch_length = flat_queryset.count()
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 621, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 559, in get_count
    return obj.get_aggregation(using, ["__count"])["__count"]
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 544, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/python_backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```